# Loading a program from the disk

Tags: operating-system

How long does it take to load a 64-KB program from a disk whose average seek time is 10 msec., whose rotation time is 20 msecs., and whose track holds 32-KB for a 2-KB page size?
The pages are spread randomly around the disk and the number of cylinders is so large
that the chance of two pages being on the same cylinder is negligible.

My solution ..
64 KB program will be organized into 2 tracks because of each track capacity is 32KB.

To load entire track we require 20msec. To load 2KB we require 1.25 msec.

I/O time =seek time+avg.rotation latency+transfer time

```
             10msec+10msec+1.25msec=21.25msec

            Since 64KB program is organized into 2 tracks then I/O time will be 2(21.25)=42.5 msec.
```

Is it correct? if so why seek time =avg rotetion latency?

Comment: I think you're missing the part about "the pages are spread randomly around the disk ...", as you seem to be assuming that the pages are all contiguously allocated...

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Well, if the pages are really spread around randomly, then a 64-KB program consisting of 2-KB pages will require 32 separate page loads, each of which must incur a seek delay and a rotational delay. It should be fairly straightforward from there...

Comment: @Kleona Do you have the official correct answer?

Comment: @Kleona According to me the correct answer is 6400msec.

Comment: @Kleona Feel free for any queries.

Comment: Regarding the last question there (why seek time = avg rotation latency) - this is just coincidental because of the numbers given. Average rotation latency is, assuming truly uniform random distribution of requests, is approximately half the full rotation period - a full rotation is the maximum latency.

Answer (score 0):

As its mentioned that: **the number of cylinders is so large that the chance of two pages being on the same cylinder is negligible.**, it simply means to load each page,we always need to move to a different `cylinder`. Therefore, we have to add `seek time`for each page, because `seek time`  is time it takes to move the arm over appropriate `cylinder`.

```
Number of pages = 64KB/2KB = 32
```

`rotation time` by definition is time it takes to get to the appropriate `sector`, once we have reached the appropriate `cylinder`.

So Time taken would be = **32*10*20 = 6400 msec**

Comment: 32*10*20 is wrong. It should be 32 * (10 + 20/2 + 1.25), as in Kleona's answer.

Comment: @twalberg what exactly are you considering rotation time here? Kindly explain.

Comment: The question states "whose rotation time is 20 msecs". That's the time for a full platter rotation. Statistics tells us that, if we can assume a uniform random distribution of access requests, the average rotational latency is approximately half that (approximately because the actual math works out a bit different if there's an odd number of sectors per cylinder vs an even one). So that's the 20/2 in my previous comment - average rotational latency is 10 ms. That, plus the 10 ms seek time and the 1.25 ms actual transfer time, is repeated for every single read.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution .
The seek plus rotational latency is 20 msec.
 For 2-KB pages, the transfer
time is 1.25 msec, for a total of 21.25 msec. 
Loading 32 of these pages will
take 680 msec. For 4-KB pages, the transfer time is doubled to 2.5 msec, so
the total time per page is 22.50 msec. Loading 16 of these pages takes 360
msec.
Now I'm confused.